# Margin not working at all

Tags: html, css

I want to put the h1 just about 3 pixels bellow the buttons class, but it doesn't seem to work even though I put:

```
margin-top:-10px;
```

Here is the preview:
http://jsfiddle.net/poyf59jv/

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use negative margin on inline-block element. You can use position:relative, but your method seems wrong anyway, try to group the title and the caption of each element would be more semantic and easy.

Comment: You should wrap all the elements that belong together inside one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap anchor tags in a div and h1 tags in another div then make a `margin-bottom: -5px` for example to the first div.

your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poyf59jv/2/) updated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding-top instead of margin as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/poyf59jv/3/

```
<div id="buttons">
    <span><a class="buttons" id="tab1" href="#">Home</a><h1>Homepage</h1></span>
    <span><a class="buttons" id="tab2" href="#">About</a><h1>About</h1></span>
</div>

#buttons{
position:absolute;
top:225px;
height:40px;
width:850px;
margin-left:30px;

}

.buttons{
display: inline-block;
width: 122px;
line-height:1px;
margin-right:6px;
text-align: center;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
color: black;
font-family: lobster;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
text-shadow: #000000 0px 0px 0.7px;
text-decoration:none !important;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing:-0.1px;
}

span {
    width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}

span h1 {
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0; 
}
```